# Base Internationalization and "Could not find a storyboard named […]"

Tags: xcode, internationalization, uistoryboard

I am using iOS 6 and trying to use base internationalization. But when I flip the switch and run, I get a "Could not find a storyboard named […]" exception.

I tried removing and adding the storyboard file both from the build phases and from the project itself to no avail. I notice in the build phases, that the storyboard is there but it is red.

Is there a trick to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the red storyboard entry in your project navigation, go to the file inspector use the button beside the file name to navigate to the file on disk:

[image: Screenshot]  <-- the button at bottom right

If this is not enough or not possible try these strategies:

- Clean project, holding down the shift key (this will clean the entire directory).
- Restart Xcode.
- Check the target in the file inspector rather than setting it in build phases.
- Try to verify that the file is not corrupted. (Change something in IB and save.)

Comment: It's not red in the project navigator; it's only red in the build phases tab.

Comment: Delete from build phases and add again.

Comment: Clean project, holding down the shift key (this will clean the entire directory). Restart Xcode. Check the target in the file inspector rather than setting it in build phases. Try to verify that the file is not corrupted. (Change something in IB and save.)

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!

Edit your answer so that I can mark it as correct!