# Storyboards are missing in "copy bundle resources"

Tags: xcode

I'm using base internationalization to internationalize my app. Once I used it, my storyboards became red in "copy bundle resources" (they were normal before I used base internationalization):
[image]

I have tried [Xcode Copy Bundle Resources can't find files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010452/xcode-copy-bundle-resources-cant-find-files), [Base internationalization and multiple storyboard not working right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773512/base-internationalization-and-multiple-storyboard-not-working-right) and [Base Internationalization and “Could not find a storyboard named […]”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848165/base-internationalization-and-could-not-find-a-storyboard-named). unfortunately, none of them worked for me.

how can I make it normal?

***edit***

this problem still exists in xcode5

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure you have all the "Localizable strings" checkboxes ticked in the file inspector when the MainStoryboard file is selected.

I had a problem that looks similar. I transitioned my project's main storyboard to use base internationalization. When selecting the MainStoryboard file, in the file inspector, I saw a new entry called Base, which was using the English localization. So, thinking that "Base" already accounted for the english part I unchecked the English "Localizable Strings" entry in the file inspector. Apparently that was the origin of my problems. After that, the MainStoryboard file would show up in red in the "Copy bundle resources" list. Checking again the English localizable strings entry fixed the problem.

Comment: yeah, this answer solved the problem! thank you! However, I think uncheck the "Localizable Strings" of default language(it typically is English) is the way recommended by Apple ..... (https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS-Legacy/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html) see the "Add a Localization" section. Furthermore, as far as I know, this problem doesn't affect anything. the project can be compiled normally, and I18n still works great. Maybe it's a bug of Xcode?

Comment: I had the exact same problem as Ausiàs. One storyboard and the localizable.strings file. My app localized perfectly but the red storyboard file bothered me. Ticking all the languages in the File Inspector under the right side panel, Utilities, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Localizable Strings" may need also first copy your storyboard elsewhere, then do the uncheck and then import your storyboards again in your xcode project.