# How to reduce compiling time with storyboards?

Tags: xcode, ios8, uistoryboard, size-classes, xcode6.3

I have this development environment:

Xcode 6.3.1 / OSX 10.10.3 / Deployment target 6.0

I'm working with storyboard since Xcode 5 but in this version (6.3.1), I have a problem with compilation time. The problem is simple, if i change anything inside storyboard when recompile the code late about 3-4 minutes and only when I change Storyboard (anything).

I believe is because every recompile generates ALL files for each posible size screen and I understand that (cause size classes), but is too slow (and annoying) in design time.

So I just want generate the size that I need to execute (design time) and when I will make a final generates for ALL SIZES.

Is it posible?

UPDATE:

I add these links as a reference but just reduce time if you don't need recompile storyboard, unfortunately I need recompile the storyboard changes.
["Storyboard are missing in copy bundle resources"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758852/storyboards-are-missing-in-copy-bundle-resources)
 ["Decreasing Storyboard compiling time"](http://Decreasing%20Storyboard%20compiling%20time%20in%20Xcode%206)

UPDATE 2: (July 2015)
After 2 months of research, I change my hard disk to a new SSD, increase to 16GB of memory the problem persist. I get a much better compiling time (5 minutes become 1:15 minutes), but its seems like a read/write problem with Storyboard XML file... so maybe there does not exist a workaround, just buy ton of patience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this situation was improve with Xcode 7 and SDK for iOS 9. Obviously, I supposed is not permanent solution but have much better performance since then.

My same project with several minutes every compilation reduce its time to 20 seconds. It's not the best but its make tolerable.

At the end, this situation is a permanent work from our Apple guys. I hope they can work like this release, with no too many new things and can improve their code.

Answer (score -1):

I could reduce the compile time for one of my storyboards by simply compressing the image used in there with [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac). The filesize of the images was amazingly reduced by almost 60% with that tool.

Compile time before: 3 minutes

Compile time afterwards: 20 seconds